# foreach loop variable in a function executing as a static variable

Tags: tcl

In my tcl code, I have a foreach loop being executed in a function. In every iteration of the function, the loop iterator is acting as a static variable as in C language instead of a local variable.

```
foreach dev_no $tmp_port {
        puts "value of dev_no is $dev_no"
```

Every time the function executes, the variable dev_no is incrementing by 1 instead of starting from 0. As a result the loop fails to execute.

Comment: What do you have in the list `tmp_port` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want [a for loop](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/for.htm).

Here is code to loop for every number zero through $tmp_port:

```
for {set dev_no 0} {$dev_no <= $tmp_port} {incr dev_no} {
        puts "value of dev_no is $dev_no"
}
```

For example, if tmp_port is 4 this would output:

```
value of dev_no is 0
value of dev_no is 1
value of dev_no is 2
value of dev_no is 3
value of dev_no is 4
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm for a description of the foreach loop construct.

In your code, dev_no will not be incremented, but it will iterate through the variable tmp_port (assuming it is a list variable).